# GoogleMobileAds not working after adding Firebase in my application

Tags: firebase, google-dfp, admob

My mobile application (iOS / Swift) uses GoogleMobileAds SDK and everything worked fine until today (display an ad in DFPBannerView).

I've added Firebase into my application and now GoogleMobileAds doesn't work anymore.

No ads are displayed and delegate methods (e.g: adViewDidReceiveAd) are not called anymore.

If I comment the line FirebaseApp.configure() in my AppDelegate, ads works again (but Firebase is disabled in that case).

I've searched and tried a lot of things since few hours (e.g: set IS_ADS_ENABLED to NO in GoogleService-Info.plist, use Firebase/AdMob instead of standalone GoogleMobileAds, etc...) but without success.

Any idea how to use GoogleMobileAds and Firebase together ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've been losing my mind over this

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be fixed in Firebase 4.8.0, released today.

Comment: It's available through Cocoapods or with this link
https://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/ios/4_8_0/Firebase-4.8.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread on Google Groups that oriented me to the good way.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/FPW3d4LKYmQ

The issue seems to be located in Firebase Performance.

If I remove that SDK from my application, ads are correctly displayed.